# Itemize in Tabular raises "Something wrong--perhaps a missing \item"

Tags: tables, lists

By trying to compile the code below the following error will be raised for each `\item` entry.

**Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item**

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    560 v. Chr. & \begin{itemize}
                     \item erster Eintrag
                     \item zweiter Eintrag
                     \item dritter Eintrag 
                  \end{itemize} \\
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `itemize` inside a `tabular` cell is not allowed.

Use:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
560 v. Chr. & erster Eintrag\\
            & zweiter Eintrag\\
            & dritter Eintrag\\ 
\end{tabular}
```

Otherwise, if you want LaTeX to automatically break the line, use:

```
\begin{tabular}{lp{5cm}}
560 v. Chr. & erster Eintrag zweiter Eintrag dritter Eintrag\\ 
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now the text is not going over the border of the document and  I haven't got any itemize symbol. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I've updated my answer to take into account your comment.

Comment: `\itemize` environment is actually allowed for "p-columns", as illustrated in [that other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148454/117801), for instance.

Answer (score 10):

`itemize` inside `tabular` is allowed, but properly used. In the following there are two examples of usage, with different outputs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

%\begin{tabular}{ll}
\begin{tabular}{lp{8cm}}
    560 v. Chr. & \begin{itemize}
                     \item erster Eintrag
                     \item zweiter Eintrag
                     \item dritter Eintrag 
                  \end{itemize} \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{lp{8cm}}
  560 v. Chr. & \parbox{7.9cm}{\begin{itemize}
                     \item erster Eintrag
                     \item zweiter Eintrag
                     \item dritter Eintrag 
                  \end{itemize} }\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to use ```tabularx```'s ```X``` option, i.e. not specifying the width of the column with ```p{}```, but adjusting it dynamically as 1/3 of ```\linewidth```? My header would be ```\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X | X | X }```