# Error on tabular; "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item." (No itemize or enumerate)

Tags: tables, errors

I know about [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49882/yet-another-perhaps-a-missing-item-error) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148451/itemize-in-tabular-raises-something-wrong-perhaps-a-missing-item) but the problem I am having does not relate to section headings, and I am not using itemize or enumerate. So they don’t help me.
As in the question title, the error message (using pdflatex) is

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

It's a latex beamer doc;

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\mode<presentation>
{    
  \usecolortheme{default} 
  \usefonttheme{default}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 


\title[Such a title]{Title}
\author{Ron Weasley}
\institute{Hogwarts}
\date{19th of January 2017}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}{Finding solutions}
Problem \(\rightarrow\) Formalism \(\rightarrow\) Result
\end{frame}


\section{Merits of Formalisms}

\begin{frame}{Instant form} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{LightConeImages/InstantLightCone}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Poincar\'e group in instant form} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
    \(P^1\) & \(P^3\) & \(M^{12}\)\\
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{LightConeImages/BackLightCone}
    \end{figure}
    &
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{LightConeImages/RightLightCone}
    \end{figure}
    &
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{LightConeImages/TurnLightCone}
    \end{figure}
    \\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Commenting out the tabular section does remove the error, so I'm sure it's that. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem;

```
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
    \(P^1\) & \(P^3\) & \(M^{12}\)\\
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{LightConeImages/BackLightCone}
    &
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{LightConeImages/RightLightCone}
    &
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{LightConeImages/TurnLightCone}
    \\
\end{tabular}
```

Basically, figures are not allowed in a tabular environment. Just use `\includegraphics` on its own.

Comment: In a `beamer` document, there's really no purpose or reason for using `figure` (and `table`) environments to begin with.

Comment: @Mico Aren't `figure` and `table` environments in a `beamer` document typically used for captioning with numbers?

Comment: @Sussch - In a `beamer` presentation document, a table's or figure's caption belong in the frame title. In my experience, there's no point in assigning numbers to these captions: If a person wants to ask the speaker, "Can you go back to table [or figure] so-and-so", they'll do so by referring to the *text* of the caption, *not* to its number. At any rate, is it reasonable to expect anyone to remember the number of the table or figure once the presentation has moved on to the next slide? That's why I wrote that there's no purpose in using `table` or `figure` environments in `beamer` documents.